# how is the best way to update a register? In performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I would like to know which is the best way to update an entity when I want to update only a few fields.

I am using C# 4.0 and EF 4.4.

The first way is:

1.- I load the register from the database.
2.- I modify the property. How the entity is in the context, Only is try to update the properties that are changed.
3.- Save the changes.

The Second option is:

1.- I attach my entity to the context
2.- Mark the properties that I want to modified in this way:

myContext.Entries(myEntity).Property("myField").IsModified = true;

3.- Save the changes.

In the first way, I do a query to get the entity and other to save the changes and in the second way I only use a query when I save the changes.

However, in my case I have a no null propery that I don't want to modified, so when I create my stub entity to attach to the context, mark as modified the property that I want and save the changes, I get a validation exception.

So I would like to know if when I have not null properties in the entity, I can use the first way or I need to use the second one.

I think that in performace it would exist a difference because I don't need load the registers from the database. is it true?

Thanks.

Comment: by "register" do you mean "row"?

Comment: The first way, you obviously can't run validations on fields you're not setting. If you need validation in that way, you'll need to fetch the entity.

Comment: but I this property is marked as not modified, why is needed to set this property?